# LINQ Group by and Sum syntax

Tags: vb.net, linq, group-by, sum, ienumerable

i have the following vb.net LINQ Query

```
Dim q = From row In dx.AsEnumerable
                Group row By G = New With {.Cat = row.Field(Of Integer)("catalogid")}.Cat,
                                 New With {.Backorder = row.Field(Of Integer)("backorder")}.Backorder Into pg = Group
                Select New With
                       {
                           .Cat = pg.Cat,
                           .Backorder = pg.Sum(Function(x) x.Backorder)
                       }
```

i have this datatable called dx

```
catalogid      backorder
1              5
1              10
2              1
2              5
```

i want to `Sum` `backorder` column where `catalogid` is the same so the result is the following

```
catalogid      backorder
1              15
2              6
```

in the Select new with part, what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following...

```
 var result = dx.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("catalogid"))
                .Select(group => group.Sum(item => item.Field<int>     ("backorder")).CopyToDataTable();
```

or

```
var result= from s in dx.AsEnumerable()
            group s by s.Field<int>("catalogid") into grp
            select new { 
            CatalogId= grp.Key, 
            Back Order = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("backorder"))
            };

DataTable datatbl = result.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: any hint on how can i put the result in a datatable or save it to the dx datatable?